Language Tex Generator
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum} %This package just generates Lorem Ipsum filler text. 
\usepackage{fullpage} % changes the margin
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{showframe} % just to show the margin lines; comment this package     out for the final version

\begin{document}

\section*{Language tree}

\begin{forest}
for tree={
    edge path={
        \noexpand\path [thick, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) --   +(0,-7pt) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
}, % this option together with setting the parent and child anchors to south and north, respectively, gives you the right-angle style for your branches
parent anchor=south,
child anchor=north,
align=center, % allows you to put line breaks within nodes
}

 [Indo-European
[Spartian
 [Dieter
 [Buffalo Spartian]


Welcome to TeX.SE.  You can format your code by highlighting and clicking {}.  But can you give some text to explain your question?  And complete your code through the end of the tex file.

Please be more specific as to what it is you're looking to accomplish.

If I remove the blank line before Indo-European and append ] ] ] \end{forest} \end{document}, then it compiles without error.  Does it not show what you want?  What do you want to happen?

@Teepeemm is right: you can't leave blank lines in a forest specification.

Welcome. // Can you please EDIT your question and put a question there? Thank you // I also assume your question is related to package forest, so I added that tag.

To long for the comment:

Your MWE (Minimal Working Example) is not complete (missed are closing brackets, \end{forest} and \end{document}
In forest environment are not allowed empty lines (they throw error Runaway argument?)
Your tree can be written with the following simplified code:

\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum} %This package just generates Lorem Ipsum filler text. 
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}

\section*{Language tree}

\begin{forest}
for tree={
parent anchor=south,
child anchor=north,
align=center, % allows you to put line breaks within nodes
}
% <--- here should not be empty line
[Indo-European
    [Spartian
        [Dieter
            [Buffalo Spartian]
        ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}


